# SonarQube 6.5 with MSBuild Runner Causes Build Failures Due to HTTP 400 Error

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are using SonarQube v6.5 with the MSBuild Runner v3.0.2.656 to analyze a bunch of C# / .NET assemblies. SonarQube is able to analyze many of our projects without an issue, but fails on others.

We see the following errors in the build logs: *(timestamps removed for clarity)*

```
INFO: Analysis report generated in 203ms, dir size=257 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 78ms, zip size=93 KB
INFO: Analysis report generated in D:\Fusion workspaces\Fusion main web services build (development)\AccessDB\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\batch-report
DEBUG: Upload report
DEBUG: POST 400 http://fusionbuilder.wsicorp.com:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=Fusion:WebServices:AccessDB&projectName=D:\Fusion%20workspaces\Fusion%20main%20web%20services%20build%20(development)\AccessDB | time=1031ms
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

On the SonarQube server, the following error also appears in the web.log:

```
INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11Processor] Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:472)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:683)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

After searching around on the forums a bit, we went through and changed all of the source files in the project to be encoded UTF-8 thinking that this might be the issue, but this did not fix the problem.

First question: is this something that is an issue with SonarQube, or is this an issue with the Tomcat J2EE container?

Second question: how can we fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error cites the headers. Any way to sniff them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this log:

> DEBUG: POST 400 http://fusionbuilder.wsicorp.com:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=Fusion:WebServices:AccessDB&projectName=D:\Fusion%20workspaces\Fusion%20main%20web%20services%20build%20(development)\AccessDB | time=1031ms

It looks like `projectName` is set to `D:\Fusion workspaces\Fusion main web services build (development)\AccessDB`, which is a very strange name for a project.

When you run the begin step with Scanner for MSBuild, you can specify the project name using the `/n` parameter, for example: `/n:"Project Name"`. I suggest to specify a project name without `D:` and without `\` characters in it.

Comment: Thank you! The issue was the naming of the project - in my haste to get our builds retrofitted, I must have copy / pasted the wrong thing.